# Struts2 taglib dates calculation remove decimals

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags, valuestack

I'm using Struts2 taglib to generate a list of descending years (`2016`, `2015`, etc..).

I'm using the date tag to get year from a `java.util.Date`, however when I use minus (`-`) operator `year` comes correct but with decimals...

**Take a look:**

```
<s:set var="currentDate" value="%{new java.util.Date()}"/>
<s:date var="currentDate2YEAR" name="#currentDate" format="yyyy" />
<br>(YEAR)  = <s:property value="#currentDate2YEAR" />
<br>(YEAR -1)  = <s:property value="#currentDate2YEAR - 1" />
```

**With this I get:**

```
(YEAR) = 2016

(YEAR -1) = 2015.0     <== I need to remove this decimal ==>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution and it works (it uses the intValue method):

```
<s:date var="currentDate2YEAR" name="#currentDate" format="yyyy" />
<br>(YEAR)  = <s:property value="#currentDate2YEAR" />
<br>(YEAR -1)  = <s:set var="year" value="#currentDate2YEAR - 1" />
<br>(YEAR -1) = <s:property value="#year.intValue()" />
```

Comment: So you're going to use additional `<s:set>` for every computation? Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35842876/1700321).

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* ways to do this, and as usual the betters are the one involving a server side method, reducing the logic in the view to the physiological minimum. By the way, if you need to do it in the view, try like this:

```
<s:set var="currentDate" value="%{new java.util.Date()}"/>
<s:set var="currentYear">
    <s:date name="#currentDate" format="yyyy" />
</s:set>
<br>(YEAR)     = <s:property value="%{#currentYear    }" />
<br>(YEAR - 1) = <s:property value="%{#currentYear - 1}" />
<br>(YEAR - 2) = <s:property value="%{#currentYear - 2}" />
```

It could also be scripted within an iterator, it would help if you could post more details about what you're actualing doing, if this doesn't work or isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't do that kind of stuff in the view, instead construct a list in the back-end end iterate it in the view.

Second: You're using some old version of Struts2 that is why this -> `<s:set value="%{new java.util.Date()}"/>` is allowed. In latest versions you cannot create a new instance in JSP in that way. You can use `<s:bean>` tag to do that.

Third: Why do you see `.0` after number? Because after the formatting, year part is actually a String and when you subtract it is converted to some floating point number.

To get around it, just do that in the server. :)

Well there is a way to do so in JSP also.

Add `h` after number (i.e. `#currentDate2YEAR - 1h`) which will indicate to OGNL that this is a `BigInteger` and not a floating point number.

```
<s:bean var="currentDate" name="java.util.Date" />
<s:date var="currentDate2YEAR" name="#currentDate" format="yyyy" />
<br>(YEAR)  = <s:property value="#currentDate2YEAR" />
<br>(YEAR -1)  = <s:property value="#currentDate2YEAR - 1h" />
```